# Using addOption in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have already a js function that inside is doing something like this:

```
db.MyCollection.find().forEach( function(item) {
  //code here....
}
```

I'm having some timeout problems so I would like to add the addOption() method to avoid the timeout, so I found this way to do it:

```
var myCursor = db.MyCollection.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout);
```

Now I need to know how should I apply it at the same time I'm using a forEach?

Comment: Your statement is correct. You need to iterate the cursor now. `myCursor.forEach(function(i){...})`

Comment: Yes. That's how you need to use it.

Comment: thank you! I'm trying that...